# Swiper me da el error "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'." no puedo solucionarlo

Tags: javascript, consola, swiper

No se que ocurre con swiper, estoy copiando de un video literalmente lo mismo y no funciona. Esta todo bien linkeado y las clases/id tienen los nombres correctos. adjunto el JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".coming-container", {
spaceBetween: 20,
loop: true,
autoplay:{
delay: 55000,
disableOnInteraction: false,
},
centeredSlides: true,
breakpoints:{
0:{
    slidesPerView: 2,
},
568:{
    slidesPerView:3,
},
768:{
    slidesPerView:4,
},
968:{
    slidesPerView:5,
  },
}, 
})
```

Supuestamente el error viene de aca:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".coming-container", {
```

En mi HTML utilizo el ".coming-container" de esta manera:

```
<div class="coming-container swiper">
            <div class="swipper-wrapper">
            <!-- Box 1 -->
            <div class="swiper-slide box">
                <div class="box-img">
                    <img src="img/img/m1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <h3>Venom</h3>
                <span>120 min | Accion</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ahora pruebo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Per aca que decis  "elemento = document.getElementById( "coming-container" )"
que vendria siendo ese elemento?

Comment: fíjate que en el "swipper-wrapper" en realidad va "swiper-wrapper", te sobro una P ahi. Viendo la documentación de la API al menos a mi me funciono bien así.